# TensorFlow:ValueError: 'images' contains no shape

Tags: tensorflow

I used TensorFlow function tf.image.resize_images to resize my image, but I got this Error in Code:
ValueError: 'images' contains no shape.
The full code is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tensorflow as tf
file = ["./1.jpg"]
f = tf.train.string_input_producer(file)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, img = reader.read(f)

img = tf.image.decode_image(img)
# img.set_shape([218,178,3])
img = tf.image.resize_images(img, [64,64])

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()    
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    image = sess.run(img)
```

The full Error information is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_read_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    img = tf.image.resize_images(img, [64,64])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py", line 724, in resize_images
    raise ValueError('\'images\' contains no shape.')
ValueError: 'images' contains no shape.
```

Then I try to fix this, but only find a way like that

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import tensorflow as tf
    file = ["./1.jpg"]
    f = tf.train.string_input_producer(file)
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, img = reader.read(f)

    img = tf.image.decode_image(img)
    # img.set_shape([218,178])
    # img = tf.image.resize_images(img, [64,64])

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()    
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        image = sess.run(img)
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [64,64])
```

Only in this way the function can work well, But I don't know why? Is the function tf.image.resize_images only take the numpy array as parameter? Or I can find another way to solve this problem? NB: img.set_shape([218,78,3]) does not work for me

Answer (score 45):

It's important to pass `expand_animations = False` as an argument:

Try:

```
tf.image.decode_image(img, expand_animations = False)
```

to make sure you have a tensor with  a 3-dimensional shape.
This problem is due to gif format because decode_gif returns a 4-D array [num_frames, height, width, 3] as opposed to other formats including decode_bmp, decode_jpeg, and decode_png, which return 3-D arrays [height, width, num_channels].

For more information check the [related documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image)

Answer (score 36):

I faced this issue recently,

```
tf.image.decode_image()
```

doesn't return tensor with shape, but my images were all in jpeg format.

So I used

```
 tf.image.decode_jpeg()
```

it returns tensor with the shape and that solved the problem. 
Note there is **tf.image.decode_png()** too.

More info can be found here [Tensorflow tf.image.decode_jpeg documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg)

Comment: Why did tensorfow avoid the shape parameter from `decode_image()`?

Comment: @alireza Akhavan answered your question below; it's because the method can also read in gifs. A bit annoying and cryptic because in the docs it says it returns a shape.

Comment: `tf.image.decode_jpeg()` worked. Isn't `tf.image.decode_image()` supposed to infer `jpeg` format automatically?

Answer (score 8):

```
image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
image_decoded = tf.cond(
      tf.image.is_jpeg(image_string),
      lambda: tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3),
      lambda: tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was feeding the raw image data directly (i.e. my input shape was `(batch_size, image_height, image_width, 3)` and I was not calling `decode_jpeg` at any point), and adding

`tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`

to the relevant Jupyter cell happened to fix the problem for me.

Don't know the root cause in my case, but the TFRecords were generated using a different Tensorflow version than that used to load the model, which I suspect is part of the problem.

Comment: Forcing the shape with `x = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.ensure_shape(x, (None, None, None, 3)))(input_image)` also works. Confusingly `layers.Reshape` does not, but I guess that's TF for you.