# Tensorflow: Convert image to rgb if grayscale

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset of rgb and grayscale images. While iterating over the dataset, I want to detect if the image is a grayscale image such that I can convert it to rgb. I wanted to use `tf.shape(image)` to detect the dimensions of the image. For a rgb image I get something like `[1, 100, 100, 3]`. For grayscale images the function returns for example `[1, 100, 100]`. I wanted to use `len(tf.shape(image))` to detect if it is of length 4 (=rgb) or length 3 (=grayscale). That did not work.

This is my code so far which did not work:

```
def process_image(image):
    # Convert numpy array to tensor
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype=tf.uint8)
    # Take care of grayscale images
    dims = len(tf.shape(image))
    if dims == 3:
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=3)
        image = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(image)
    return image
```

Is there an alternative way to convert grayscale images to rgb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, I wanted to load rgb and greyscale images in one go. Tensorflow supports setting the channel number when reading in the images. So if the images have different numbers of channels, this might be what you are looking for:

```
# to get greyscale:
tf.io.decode_image(raw_img, expand_animations = False, dtype=tf.float32, channels=1)

# to get rgb:
tf.io.decode_image(raw_img, expand_animations = False, dtype=tf.float32, channels=3)
```

-> You can even do both on the same image and inside `tf.data.Dataset` mappings!

You now have to set the `channels` variable to match the shape you need, so all the loaded images will be of that shape. Than you could reshape without a condition.

This also allows you to directly load a grayscale image to RGB in Tensorflow. Here an example:

```
    >> a = Image.open(r"Path/to/rgb_img.JPG")
    >> np.array(a).shape
    (666, 1050, 3)
    >> a = a.convert('L')
    >> np.array(a).shape
    (666, 1050)
    >> b = np.array(a)
    >> im = Image.fromarray(b) 
    >> im.save(r"Path/to/now_it_is_greyscale.jpg")
    >> raw_img = tf.io.read_file(r"Path/to/now_it_is_greyscale.jpg")
    >> img = tf.io.decode_image(raw_img, dtype=tf.float32, channels=3)
    >> img.shape
    TensorShape([666, 1050, 3])
    >> img = tf.io.decode_image(raw_img, dtype=tf.float32, channels=1)
    >> img.shape
    TensorShape([666, 1050, 1])
```

Use `expand_animations = False` if you get `ValueError: 'images' contains no shape.`! See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944421/9621080

Comment: Does that mean that I can load a grayscale image directly into a RGB image by using `tf.io.decode_image(raw_img, expand_animations=False, dtype=tf.float32, channels=3)`?

Comment: Yes, it works :)  I will update my answer regarding that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function like this for that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def process_image(image):
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype=tf.uint8)
    image_rgb =  tf.cond(tf.rank(image) < 4,
                         lambda: tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.expand_dims(image, -1)),
                         lambda: tf.identity(image))
    # Add shape information
    s = image.shape
    image_rgb.set_shape(s)
    if s.ndims is not None and s.ndims < 4:
        image_rgb.set_shape(s.concatenate(3))
    return image_rgb
```

Comment: Do I need the `tf.identity()` function in this case?

Comment: @Samuel I tend to put it to make more explicit that I am creating a new node in the graph that is the result (depends on) the conditional operation. However, I think it is not really necessary (it might make a difference if `image` where a variable and updates were being applied to it, but not in most cases I think).

Comment: I just saw that I get an error if I use your code when I want to resize the image returned by `process_image()`. It says `ValueError: 'images' contains no shape` when I use `image = tf.image.resize_images(image, size=[64,64])` after using `process_image(image)`. Why is that the case?

Comment: @Samuel Right, `tf.cond` does not keep the shape information (not sure if ever or in this case). I have modified the function to restore it after when possible.