# GauGan TensorFlow ValueError: 'images' contains no shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I need to use GauGan for doodle to image process. Online sites with this possibilities I didn't find. So I found some code and guides to use GauGan in google collab. [code link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/gaugan.py). But I got `ValueError: 'images' contains no shape.` I was searching this error but answers there did not help. E.g.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942729/tensorflowvalueerror-images-contains-no-shape). I think It can be TensorFlow update issue. Code in the example already not suited to updated module version. But I don't know. 2 hours I have tried to use code changes or something and didn't get solution.

```
/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileqnller0o.py in tf__call(self, input_tensor, raw_mask)
      8                 do_return = False
      9                 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
---> 10                 mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).image.resize, (ag__.ld(raw_mask), ag__.ld(self).resize_shape), dict(method='nearest'), fscope)
     11                 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv, (ag__.ld(mask),), None, fscope)
     12                 gamma = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv_gamma, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "<ipython-input-13-d9b453a0b120>", line 134, in train_step
        discriminator_loss = self.train_discriminator(
    File "<ipython-input-13-d9b453a0b120>", line 81, in train_discriminator
        fake_images = self.generator([latent_vector, labels])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filewy308sf_.py", line 10, in tf__call
        x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).spade_1, (ag__.ld(input_tensor), ag__.ld(mask)), None, fscope)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileqnller0o.py", line 10, in tf__call
        mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).image.resize, (ag__.ld(raw_mask), ag__.ld(self).resize_shape), dict(method='nearest'), fscope)

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'res_block_34' (type ResBlock).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "<ipython-input-35-7d3bd05b696f>", line 43, in call  *
            x = self.spade_1(input_tensor, mask)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileqnller0o.py", line 10, in tf__call
            mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).image.resize, (ag__.ld(raw_mask), ag__.ld(self).resize_shape), dict(method='nearest'), fscope)
    
        ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'spade' (type SPADE).
        
        in user code:
        
            File "<ipython-input-6-7d3bd05b696f>", line 13, in call  *
                mask = tf.image.resize(raw_mask, self.resize_shape, method="nearest")
        
            ValueError: 'images' contains no shape.
        
        
        Call arguments received by layer 'spade' (type SPADE):
          • input_tensor=tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 4, 4, 1024), dtype=float32)
          • raw_mask=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'res_block_34' (type ResBlock):
      • input_tensor=tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 4, 4, 1024), dtype=float32)
      • mask=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
```

So there are someone who know how to fix it ?

One of my ideas is something in `resize` function.

```
def build(self, input_shape):
        self.resize_shape = input_shape[1:3]

def call(self, input_tensor, raw_mask):
    mask = tf.image.resize(raw_mask, self.resize_shape, method="nearest")
```

Maybe `resize_shape` is bad handled in new TensorFlow version.